# Calculate variable from data.frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure this is obvious, but I can't figure it out.

I have a data.frame, and want to calculate a variable from several types.

```
df = data.frame(time = rep(seq(10),each=2),Type=rep(c("A","B"),times=10),value = runif(20))
```

I want a new data.frame, with A / B for each time point.

I've tried:

```
df2 <- df |> group_by(time) |> mutate(new_value= value[Type=="A"] / value[Type=="B"],.keep="none")
```

But I still have a new_value twice for each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option may be to reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` and then create the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = value) %>% 
   mutate(new_value = A/B)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
    time     A     B new_value
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     1 0.565 0.913     0.618
 2     2 0.902 0.274     3.29 
 3     3 0.321 0.986     0.326
 4     4 0.620 0.937     0.661
 5     5 0.467 0.407     1.15 
 6     6 0.659 0.152     4.33 
 7     7 0.573 0.239     2.40 
 8     8 0.962 0.601     1.60 
 9     9 0.515 0.403     1.28 
10    10 0.880 0.364     2.42
```

---

`mutate` creates or modifies a column in the original dataset, thus it returns the same number of rows.  Instead, it may be better to use `summarise` if we want `unique` values (but here the 'Type' will be lost)

```
df |> 
  group_by(time) |> 
  summarise(new_value= value[Type=="A"] / value[Type=="B"])
```

In addition, this works only when the count of 'A', 'B' elements per 'time' is the same